# Custom Environment with Parentheses around Optional Parameter

Tags: environments, conditionals

I am trying to create a custom "proof" environment that behaves as follows:

`\begin{proof}\end{proof}` should produce `\textit{Proof.}`, while `\begin{proof}{method}\end{proof}` should produce `\textit{Proof (method).}`. Here's what I have right now:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newenvironment{proof}[1]
    {\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\textit{Proof
        {\ifthenelse
            {\isempty{#1}}
            {}
            {(#1)}
    }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}{by contradiction}
    1
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
    2
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, I cannot get `#1` in parentheses as they always disappear upon compiling. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with. This will include any packages needed to make the fragment compile.

Comment: @AlanMunn Fixed! Thank you.

Comment: Optional arguments are usually introduced with `[...]`. That would make things a lot easier.  Would that be an acceptable syntax?

Comment: @AlanMunn I seem to run into the same issues when I have that. [1][] makes all the arguments disappear, as I'm sure you can see on your end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional arguments are usually introduced with `[...]`, and since this is an optional argument to the environment, I think it makes sense to use that syntax. So here's a version that does exactly that:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{proof}{o}{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\textit{Proof}}
    {\textit{Proof (#1)}}
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[by contradiction]
    1
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
    2
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Alan Munn already beat me to it and probably has a nicer solution. But since I learned that myself just now, here is an alternative which uses the *environ* package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{inner}[1][]{%
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
  \itshape Proof.
  \ifthenelse
  {\isempty{#1}}
  {\BODY}
  {(#1) \BODY}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{inner}[by contradiction]
   1
\end{inner}

\begin{inner}
    2
\end{inner}

\end{document}
```

[image]